# Initialize std::variant<Pointer, Pointer>?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, variant

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
class X
{
  std::variant<CComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget>, CComPtr<ID2D1DCRenderTarget>> mpRenderTarget;
  void init();
}

// To early to know which member we need, it's no value until derived class calls init() method.
X::X() : mpRenderTarget(nullptr)

void X::init()
{
   // Only here it is known what exactly to initialize!
   // and this is going to be in derived class, this one pure virtual.
}
```

Problem is that this constructor doesn't compile, because variant initialization is not valid,
however if I omit initialization of `mpRenderTarget` in constructor then another problem is that
the variant is "ilformed" according to standard.

I just want to initalize it to some default in constructor, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply assign it a default value of *one* of the types:

```
X::X() : mpRenderTarget(CComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget>{}) {}
```

You can be explicit about the default pointer value being `nullptr` as well:

```
X::X() : mpRenderTarget(CComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget>{nullptr}) {}
```

The important part is that you *must* specify which of the `variant` types you want to initialize the object with.

Comment: Ah nice, I guess `mpRenderTarget(CComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget>(nullptr))` is valid too, the point is to be explicit about NULL-es?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that the default value for this pointer type is `nullptr`, but there's no harm in being explicit.